# Approximation of binary entropy function where weighted sum has minimum at same input

Tags: optimization, approximation, entropy

I'm trying to find ways to find an approximation of a function, because said function is "too much of a hassle" to calculate manually (e.g. with a simple calculator). To be specific, this is the function that's "too much of a hassle" to calculate manually:

$B(q) = - (q \log q + (1 - q) \log (1 - q))$

This function is used such: Given a set $A$ with elements of the form $(p,n)$, where $p,n \in \mathbb{N}$, define

$R(A) = \sum_{(p,n) \in A} (p + n) B(\frac{p}{p + n})$

Given multiple sets $A_1$, $A_2$, ... $A_n$ I need to find the $A_i$ which gives the minimum value for $R(A_i)$. I don't care for the actual value $R(A_i)$, I just need to identify $A_i$.

Is there a way to "simplify" $B(q)$ such that I can calculate it with less operations but still correctly identify which $A_i$ (from some given set of such sets) has the lowest value?

---

Background: I need to train/build decision trees, manually (without access to a computer) and under tight time constraints. $B(q)$ is the [binary entropy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function). A set $A$ stands for an attribute (of the training set), each pair $(p,n)$ of it defines the number of positive ($p$) and negative ($n$) training samples per attribute value (the set contains one pair for each attribute value). $R(A)$ is the "remaining entropy" after using the attribute for the next decision. The less entropy remains, the higher the information gain. Thus the attribute with the minimal $R(A)$ is the best choice for the next decision.

Comment: I'd appreciate help with tagging and the title.

Comment: Note: I'm asking this here instead of cs.stackexchange.com because the question hasn't really much to do with its intended application, IMO.

Comment: What type of operations should an (approximate) formula for $B(q)$ consist of in order to be less of a hassle than its definition? Would, say, a polynomial approximation such as a (truncated) [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function#Taylor_series) be acceptable?

Comment: @Stelios Hm, if we can limit the Taylor series to two terms its still less key presses on my calculator than the original definition. How can I make sure that the approximation is accurate enough?

Comment: So, you are looking for an approximation with the minimum number of key presses? Interesting! Your task sounds to me more of an enginnering than mathematical problem. In any case, I guess it will be difficult to find a "low-key" approximation that will guarantee the same decision in all cases as if the actual definition of B(q) was used. You will probably need to experiment with the various approximations on test (artificially generated) data to see if the performance loss is tolerable.